# What does this line of Powershell do?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

This is the script I wrote based on my own online research, but I am new to PowerShell and don't know what the first line does exactly. Is it needed if the script is run locally on a windows 10 pc, or is that only for working with domains / Active Directory / on a windows server?

The purpose of this script is to retrieve a copy of the Bitlocker recovery key using the PowerShell console.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
        # what does this line do?
           Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
        # move to script folder to run ".\Get-BitlockerRecovery.ps1"
           cd PS_scripts
        # run ".\Get-BitlockerRecovery.ps1"
           .\Get-BitlockerRecovery.ps1
        # return to starting point
           cd ..
```

Here is the code inside of ".\Get-BitlockerRecovery.ps1":

```
# Identify all Bitlocker volumes
$BitlockerVolumers = Get-BitLockerVolume

# For each volume (object), get the RecoveryPassowrd and display it.
$BitlockerVolumers |
    ForEach-Object {
        $MountPoint = $_.MountPoint 
        $RecoveryKey = [string]($_.KeyProtector).RecoveryPassword       
        if ($RecoveryKey.Length -gt 5) {
            Write-Output ("The drive $MountPoint has a recovery key $RecoveryKey.")
        }        
    }
```

I found this, but don't fully understand if it is applicable to my case since it mentions "for Windows server computers."

> RemoteSigned. Requires that all scripts and configuration files downloaded from the Internet are signed by a trusted publisher. The default execution policy for Windows server computers.
> Link : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1

Again, I'm new to PowerShell, so ELI5, please.
Also, if you catch any other errors elsewhere, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to PowerShell and don't know what the first line does exactly.

PowerShell was designed to be more secure than batch. Therefore, by default, running PowerShell scripts is limited by Windows. It's dangerous to allow script execution if that (perhaps unauthorized) script is downloading malicious software or creating other security holes.

In the case of the first line, the Execution Policy (limits placed on the script) are being set so that scripts created locally will run without problems, but scripts fetched from another computer (e.g. the internet) as determined by Windows, have additional restrictions placed on them.

> Is it needed if the script is run locally on a Windows 10 PC?

As far as I am aware, no new installation of (non-Server) Windows allows PowerShell scripts to be run automatically -- an Execution Policy needs to be set to allow scripts to run (though non-Windows computers have their execution policies set to `Unrestricted` as of PowerShell 6.0+, apparently). However, this does not necessarily need to be done for every script. That is, you can change these settings once from the command line rather than on a per-script basis.

> I found this, but don't fully understand if it is applicable to my case since it mentions "for Windows server computers."

It is stating that `RemoteSigned` is the default Execution Policy for PowerShell on Windows Server, as opposed to `Undefined` (I believe) for non-Server versions of Windows -- not that it applies to Window Server only.

[The official documentation for the `Set-Execution` cmdlet can be found here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: [Default Execution Policy for Windows is Restricted while it's Remote Signed for Windows Server.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#parameters).  This is confirmed by the following statement: "If the execution policy in all scopes is Undefined, the effective execution policy is Restricted."

Comment: So the purpose of the line in the script, it’s to temporarily change the execution policy to Remote Signed, it does nothing if it’s already set to Remote Signed.